# How to check out from svn and git in the same Jenkins job?

Tags: svn, git, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which need to check out some source code located in svn and some located in git repositories. Is there any nice way to set up Jenkins to checking out from both?

Right now, I have Jenkins set up to check out from subversion and I am planning to run a script to get the sources I need from git before doing the build step.

Any suggestions of a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin

However, using it has some caveats, so read through the entire page.

The other thing to do would be to checkout from one of the SCMs using Jenkins, and from the other using the command line in "Execute Shell" or "Execute Batch Command". However, this will not build on changes for the second SCM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do other way around. Use GIT plugin provided with Jenkins to clone and you can use different client tools available for SVN.